# Resize a Xib to screen size swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, xib

I am loading a XIB on top of a camera view, however I can't seem to find out how to resize the XIB to fit different screen sizes. please se below how my XIB is set up.

[image]

any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2):

Before you add the view as a subview, set the view's frame to the parent view's bounds. Assuming the parent view is named *parentview* and the XIB you are loading is called *subview*:

```
subview.frame = parentview.bounds
parentview.addSubview(subview)
```